# windows system backup does not recognize second hard disk anymore

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup

I used to take my windows system backups on D: (windows 7 is installed on C:). D: is a 2x300GB RAID0 installation and was (and still is) working fine. Apart from backups, D: was also my big-files storage system (movies, pictures, mp3s, etc)

Since I installed Ubuntu on C: as a dual-boot with my Windows 7 installation (for my job needs), Windows cannot recognize D: as an external backup media, anymore. Although I can use D: as before (watch movies, copy files, listen to music) when I open Windows System Backup tool, the only option I get to backup my data is my DVD.

I think there is something wrong, here. Any help would be appreciated because I am totally lost.

Comment: It seems that the problem was that although ubuntu installed on SATA3 (where windows lies), it modified the boot record of RAID because RAID is installed in SATA0+SATA1.